# Editable DataGridView - detecting new rows and edited rows, and responding accordingly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

A `DataGridView` with editable rows and columns. A `DataTable` is being used as the `DataSource`.

How can I detect the following cases?

1. One of the entries is changed - this should then cause an appropriate method to execute, which takes the data in that row as arguments.
2. A brand new entry is added - this should then cause a different method to execute, to add it to the `DataTable`. Again, it takes the data in that row as arguments.

I assume there are appropriate events for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach an event handler to the bound DataTable's [RowChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rowchanging?view=netcore-3.1) or [RowChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rowchanged?view=netcore-3.1) (depending on when you want to know) events, then you can examine the [DataRowChangeEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowchangeeventargs?view=netcore-3.1) `Action` property to know if it was an add or modify and invoke a relevant method accordingly

Re the final sentence of 2), you don't need to have the invoked method add the row to the datatable - the DGV will do that (thereby causing these events); just attach to your preferred event (if you want to know before the row is added use ...Changing) and react to the row accordingly